# Federated learning with tensorflow

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, tclientdataset

```
test_data = tff.python.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
      client_ids=test_client_ids,
      serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn   
    )
print(test_data)
```

After running the above code I have got the below error...
module 'tensorflow_federated.python.simulation.datasets' has no attribute 'ClientData'

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Tensorflow Federated you are using. Based on your code, you maybe using `tensorflow_federated=0.20.0`. For that, instead of using `tff.python.simulation.datasets.ClientData`, use `tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData` as follows:

```py
test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
      client_ids=test_client_ids,
      serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn   
    )
```

This should sort out the mentioned error.
If you've already done it with another approach, Kindly share that.